# huawei e800 expresscard modem not being recognized by manjaro

Tags: network-interface, manjaro, modem, huawei

I'm trying to get a [Huawei e800](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ya68876Vd2U/UBk5949-o_I/AAAAAAAABdM/ZcYOnwUbDWQ/s1600/huawei+e800.jpg) expresscard / PCMCIA card modem to work in manjaro linux, but modemmanager is not detecting it at all, let alone let me configure a connection with it.
The status light is blinking blue every 2 sec. or so. I know (because it worked on the same laptop under ubuntu) that it shows permanent green, if it's ready for use.
Any pointers where to start, what to check, etc.?

I also used `modemmanager`, but that doesn't detect anything either.

Comment: Maybe do mount it?

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto where do I start with that? Google is only bringing up infos on mounting storage cards (SD, etc.), not this type of card.

Comment: I use ``networkmanager`` in XFCE and system see my modem. I create connection and all works!

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto when I want to add a moblie connection via the network manger, it does not let me select any device to use for it, because it doesn't detect the card.